# Should a website storage Airbnb users' passwords？

Tags: passwords

I just entered a company which is developing a website supporting hosts in Airbnb. Basically, this website will give the recommending price for hosts after they login in the Airbnb.

I noticed that the website have stored the hosts' passwords  of Airbnb in database. The passwords are stored in secret code, but it can be encrypted by a key. When a host wants to update the price on this site, the site will send a request to Airbnb to get the token with the password stored in database.

Websites such as Beyondpricing have similar function. I am wondering how they realised it. Should a website storage Airbnb users' passwords？

Comment: No. Even Airbnb shouldn't be storing the actual passwords. Encryption isn't sufficient, they should be irreversibly hashed before storage.

Comment: Keeping them in sync is another issue. Also why not get Airbnb to do the authentication and get the web site a key for that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule is passwords should always be hashed to protect from improper use.

In this case your company (and likely others) are encouraging AirBnB customers to break AirBnB's Terms of Service, from their website:

> You are responsible for safeguarding your password. You agree that you will not disclose your password to any third party.